# Create calendar events with a Subscribed URL

Tags: calendar

I've been developing an iCal Service that **publish an ical file as an URL**, so I can easily subscribe to this URL and I will get out-of-box all my events, alarms and todo's.

**The problem I'm facing** is that **I can't create a new event** back to my subscribed calendar, unless I use Mozilla Thunderbird (with Lightning) as any other calendar application gives me no change to add a new event or edit an existing event.

All apps seam to treat Subscribed URL's as **Read-Only Calendars**.

Can anyone give me a **Why** or any App that **gives this ability**?

I even bought some 3rd party calendars for iDevices and no one gives this ability as well, neither desktop apps suck **Mac iCal** or **Outlook**, or any web app such **Google Calendar**.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.